# Trigger click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Edit:
Thank you so much for all the effort, got all my code running now!

I want to trigger a click on https://shop.adidas.ae/en/stan-smith-shoes/S82255.html (to make a shoe bot).
Why does this code not work to trigger the size type button?

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('select.product-type.js-size-type').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

This is the select button:

```
<select class="product-type js-size-type">
```

This is what chrome console says

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:41
```

*Updated:*

My manifest of the chrome extension:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.adidas.ae/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "yeezyCopper.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

YeezyCopper.js :

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('select.product-type.js-size-type').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to put it in on ready: `$(function(){ $('select.product-type.js-size-type').trigger('click'); })`

Comment: 1000 may be insufficient. Use a bigger timeout or MutationObserver to watch for the elements. [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Adam, your code does literally nothing, so no error code from the console...

Comment: wOxxOm, I dont think the timeout should be a probably since the page is already loaded when typing into the console. Let me have a look at the MutationObserver...

Comment: Do you put your code in a `script` element? In that case `$` will be used from the page script, which is not jQuery but PrototypeJS.

Comment: I use it in a chrome extension in a javascript file.

Comment: If you're asking about a chrome extension, you pretty much must post the manifest.json file, and tell us which js file has the code you're showing us.  But trim it down to a [mcve] first.

Comment: @Teepeemm Updated my question and trimmed it down. I dont think it has anything to do with the extension though. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: My thought is that it could be the same problem as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28399358/2336725) (ignore the question).  Can you trigger the change event using regular javascript?

Comment: `function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
eventFire(document.getElementById('product-type js-size-type'), 'click');`

Comment: @Teepeemm So this is what I found after a quick search and I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of null
    at eventFire (yeezyCopper.js:2)
    at yeezyCopper.js:10
eventFire @ yeezyCopper.js:2
(anonymous) @ yeezyCopper.js:10`

Comment: However, I read that it should work in console which it does not for me...

Comment: Just realized I forgot to change to getelementbyclassname. I'm gonna try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works properly, but the "click" event triggered programmatically will not open the `select` option list.

See [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show its option list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

You can test that it works by adding your own `onclick` event for that element and then triggering the `click` event.

Answer (score -3):

Update

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('select.product-type.js-size-type').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('select .product-type.js-size-type').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: does not work and i do not know why it should. My code works on other web pages as well...

Comment: Ahh, I missed earlier, you need to put space in between type and JS

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
   $('.select.product-type .js-size-type').trigger('click');
}, 1000);

Comment: This is one element, so shouldnt I exchange all the spaces with dots? Thanks for the help

Comment: No, in your example, there are two classes "product-type" and "js-size-type", that's why you should use "." to start class name, and space as usual. make sense ??

Comment: Ok i get what you mean but it still does not change anything.

Comment: Are you still getting same error ? If yes, can you share complete block of code to look into ?

Comment: Yes its still the same error. This is basically the only thing I wanna do right now (actually I want to be able to click on a specific size but doesnt matter if I cant click on this element). I have manifest for the chrome extension, the javascript file and of course jquery file. However, I am trying to get this code to work in the chrome console at the moment. Thanks again

Comment: setTimeout(function () { $('.size-dropdown-block .ffSelectButton').trigger('click'); }, 1000)

Comment: This code works for http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-uncaged-shoes/BA7997.html adidas us with no problem

Comment: @RakeshYadav You've not formatted your code, so it's hard to tell what you mean.  But changing `select` to `.select` would miss the element in question, because it would go from looking for a `select` tag to looking for a `select` class, which isn't present.

Comment: You've still not properly formatted your code (it also doesn't help that you don't explain what change you're recommending).  But changing `select.product-type` to `select .product-type` (with a space) will again miss the element because it will look for a `product-type` class *within* the `select` tag, which doesn't exist.