# How to trigger click on a button

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've [this page](https://www.flipkart.com/kemei-km-1006-high-precision-hair-beard-trimmer-men/p/itme8gdd7zk7gyz7?pid=SHVEH782895ZGURK&otracker=hp_omu_Deals%20of%20the%20Day_2_Just%20%E2%82%B9349_8849cc32-8e31-4ec0-bdd2-937feda25f24). I need to trigger a click on the BUY NOW button on this page using AngularJS.

I've tried these ways to click on this "BUY NOW" in content script(myscript.js)  but does not work:

```
   angular.element($('ul form button:contains("BUY NOW")').get(0)).triggerHandler('click');

       $('ul form button:contains("BUY NOW")').get(0).click();

        $('ul form button:contains("BUY NOW")').get(0).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true
        }));
```

The manifest.json looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": false,
            "matches": ["*://www.flipkart.com/*"],
            "css": [ "jqueryui/jquery-ui.css", "js/slidenavi/sidenavi-right.css","main.css", "js/bootstrap-switch-master/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css"],
            "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js","js/angular.min.js", "js/jquery.cookie.js", "jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js","js/slidenavi/SideNavi.js", "client_server_common.js", "user-selections.js",
                "jquery.countdown.min.js", "js/bootstrap-switch-master/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js", "js/cryptojs/rollups/md5.js",  "common.js",
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

**What is the way to make it work?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with this code; it simulates a mouse left click on the element by a quick succession of mousedown, mouseup and click events fired in the center of the button:

```
var simulateMouseEvent = function(element, eventName, coordX, coordY) {
  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventName, {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: coordX,
    clientY: coordY,
    button: 0
  }));
};

var theButton = document.querySelector('ul form button');

var box = theButton.getBoundingClientRect(),
        coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
        coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;

simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "mousedown", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "mouseup", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, "click", coordX, coordY);
```

Comment: I've another select element but this technique is not working. Even after selecting an option, it is still asking to select an option. Anything more to be done?

Comment: You can't open a select element's option list with Javascript. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368802/trigger-click-not-working/42375182#42375182).

Answer (score -2):

What about Vanilla JS, noone prohibited?

Such as "onlick/click"?

```
function ae(a,b,c) {
 if (a.addEventListener)
     a.addEventListener (b,c,false);
 else if (a.attachEvent)
     a.attachEvent ('on'+b,c); 
}
function re(a,b,c) {
 if (a.removeEventListener) 
    a.removeEventListener (b,c,false);
 if (a.detachEvent)
    a.detachEvent ('on'+b,c); 
}
```

Comment: What is it and how to use it?

Comment: Does not demonstrate how to trigger the click.