# Programmatically sending keypress event

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making an autofill to fill the values automatically.

I've [this pag](https://ecom.airtelmoney.in/irctc/#/login?encdata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e using AngularJS. When I copy the mobile number using `$("input[name='username']").val('9999999999')` it does not cause change event be fired upon which "*Get OTP*" link should be activated.

Sometime back I has asked similar question : [How to trigger click on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291181/how-to-trigger-click-on-a-button)

I've tried many ways like [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) but I'm not able to make it work.

I've also tried sending focus-in event, then simulated mouse click within it, then copying the value then simulating mouse click on a different element etc.

What could be the way to make it work?

Comment: Simply trigger `input` or `change` event yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm that does not work with Angularjs based pages

Comment: Depends on how you trigger the event probably. Anyway, try `document.execCommand('insertText', false, '999')` (first focus the element)

Comment: @wOxxOm yes that's working? What's the magic behind it?

Comment: It's the only method that imitates real user input by design.

Answer (score 0):

This is your `textChanged()` function which is called initially and whenever text is changed:

```
a.textChanged = function() {
    a.isMobCollapse = "collapse", a.username && (a.errorMsg = "", a.user.otp = "", s(a.username) && 10 == a.username.length ? (a["continue"] = "enabled", 
    a.isEmailOrMobile = "mobile") : a["continue"] = "disabled");
}
```

Now this function doesn't check for value `$("input[name='username']").val()`, it checks for ng-model value `10 == a.username.length`. That's why your jquery code has no effect.

Just transfer all the logic inside angular scope and instead of setting like this

```
$("input[name='username']").val('9999999999')
```

initialize angular model like this:

```
a.username = '9999999999';
```

Comment: for doing `a.username = '999999999'` will I need to include the angularjs in my extension content script?

Comment: @user5858 you need to write this code in the same scope. Its better to write it just below the `a.textChanged()` method in the same file.

Comment: What do you mean by same scope? In the actual site code?