# Google Docs - programmatically send mouse click to an item in outline pane

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

In Google Docs you can open outline pane and see all headers in the document, you can also click on an header and the view will scroll to header.

My question is how simulate mouse click programmatically with JS in Chrome extention, to scroll the view to the desired header?

I tryed following code but nothing hapend:

```js
// usage: eventFire(document.getElementById('mytest1'), 'click');
function eventFire(el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}
```

The headers is an `div` elements with `class="navigation-item-content navigation-item-level-2"`, When I look in chrome dev tools > event listeners, these elements do not have any event listeners.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43331339/3930351)

Comment: @IvánNokonoko It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43331339/3930351):

Try with this code; it simulates a mouse left click on the element by a quick succession of mousedown, mouseup and click events fired in the center of the element:

```
var simulateMouseEvent = function(element, eventName, coordX, coordY) {
  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventName, {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: coordX,
    clientY: coordY,
    button: 0
  }));
};

var elementToClick = document.querySelector('#mytest1');

var box = elementToClick.getBoundingClientRect(),
    coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
    coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;

simulateMouseEvent (elementToClick, "mousedown", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (elementToClick, "mouseup", coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (elementToClick, "click", coordX, coordY);
```

Comment: Thanks to you, my Read Aloud Chrome extension will now be supporting Google Play books and Google Slides!

Comment: @HaiPhan Happy to help :)

Comment: It looks like I have to use all 3 events in this specific order. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @TomP That's the order mouse events are triggered when you click with your mouse. The code just mimics that.