# Enter full screen automatically by inserting script in a webpage using requestly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-injection, requestly

I want to go into full-screen mode (F11) on certain pages. For this, I am using [Requestly chrome extension](https://requestly.io) to insert a script on a webpage.

Here is the script

```js
document.body.requestFullscreen();
```

When I run this script directly in the console, I am able to go into full-screen mode. However, when Requestly is executing the script, the script is being executed but the full-screen mode is not triggered.

Even [MDN Documentation of requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) doesn't provide any additional information about this.

Need to understand if there are technical limitations about this `requestFullscreen()` API that this has to be user-intent driven like click etc and cannot be automatically called?

Comment: in sometime we need some click listener for triggering script or you can write it on javacript onready or onload function.

Comment: I believe that's one of those things that require the user to interact with the page first. Try executing in on a button click.

Comment: "This method must be called while responding to a user interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise it will fail." [Read more..](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** This is not possible to auto-trigger full-screen mode using Script Insertion. It has to be based on user Interaction.

As per [requestFullscreen MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)

> This method must be called while responding to user interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise, it will fail.

I tried triggering an automatic click on a button dynamically inserted into the page but we get the same error.

[image]

Here's [the Insert Script](https://requestly.io/feature/insert-custom-scripts/) Rule I created in Requestly

[image]

Comment: Have you tried triggering the click event using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068681/3930351)?