# How do I auto login to ADP website using javascript in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to make an auto login for ADP.com. But I can't get the buttons to unlock.  The next button and sign in button stays grayed out.  What javascript commands do I need to unlock the buttons.

Website link is:
(https://online.adp.com/signin/v1/?APPID=Pin4NAS&productId=80e309c3-709e-bae1-e053-3505430b5495&returnURL=https://login.adp.com&callingAppId=landing&TARGET=-SM-https://login.adp.com/ee/getProducts?event=Next&userSelected=anActiveEmployee&transId=7AY-008-5MA6NK)

I can enter user name using this:

```
document.getElementById('login-form_username').value = 'username'
```

But then next button is still grayed out and I can't click it to go to next step of entering password.

If I manually enter the username using my keyboard the button unlocks and I can then use the following to click the next button:

```
document.getElementById('verifUseridBtn').click()
```

I can enter the password using this:

```
document.getElementById('login-form_password').value = 'password'
```

Again after entering the password via javascript the sign in button is still grayed out and I can't click it to sign in.

I don't understand what I need to do to trigger the buttons to allow clicking.  When I manually type in the text fields that unlocks the button but I need to unlock the button via javascript.  I tried various java script commands to trigger a key press but I must not be doing it correctly because it did not enter anything in the text box and it didn't unlock the button.

I tried forcefully unlocking the buttons by setting disabled = false via javascript on the button but that seems to only unlock the button when I'm offline.  When I'm online I'm guessing some script is re-locking the button after I unlock it.  So there seems to be some events that are needed or checked that then trigger the code to do some stuff and unlock the button.

Comment: The event may be checking for a "trusted" human navigation or event (click/tab/keypress), which is likely not possible outside of something like Selenium. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059006/simulate-a-real-human-mouse-click-in-pure-javascript

Comment: So I tried that link you posted. The solution shows how to simulate clicking on a button.  I tried it out on the language selector button and that worked.  However when I tried to use it to click the text box/input it did not work.  Someone else left a comment on the solution stating that it does not work on an input.  If someone can point to a similar solution that works on an input that may help.

Comment: The "trusted" flag cannot be manipulated with JavaScript, it would be a grave security concern, hence the mention of an trust user automation solution (e.g. Selenium).

Comment: Shoot, that really sucks.  From what I can tell selenium is more of a testing tool.  I was hoping to make a browser extension that has this feature and talks to my desktop software that I'm making.  This is for a product I'm trying to sell.  It's just one small part of the product.  Selenium seems to only work on python, Java, and C#.  Python doesn't have a great executable solution.  C# is kind of specific to windows, and Java well just sucks.  I always hate it when a software requires me to install java.  I guess I just need to compromise somewhere.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but there's not too many portable solutions that don't require some form of scripting language or framework installation.  C# is available on most platforms these days through DotNetCore.   In regards to coding against ADP, I think the "official" method is through their APIs https://developers.adp.com/build/api-explorer.  As far the rest (Python, Java), there're ways to bundle them into desktop applications so they don't need to be preinstalled, but it's not trivial.

Comment: I spent a little bit of time trying to get the ADP API working but no success yet.  One thing I looked at for the API suggested that user needs to purchase the API feature to use the API.  If that's the case then it's not a solution.  Setting up the API has just been taking forever between the customers IT department and ADP.  It's really frustrating to figure out the API because I personally don't even have an ADP account and a lot of stuff for it is behind a login wall.  So to make any progress with ADP I need work with a customer to use their ADP account.

Comment: The other problem about the ADP API is the API key generation process takes too long to complete the whole process.  I can't imaging making every user go through that painful process.  The goal of my product is to make APD and integrating other software with ADP more user friendly and the key generation needed for the API is the exact opposite of user friendly.  Even if I automate the whole process the time for approval is too long.