# How can I remove a color input's border?

Tags: javascript, html

I use a JavaScript-generated HTML5 color picker element to let the user set the color of another element. When the browser executes `input type="color"` it draws a rectangle that shows the currently selected color. I name this rectangle the "color well". The color well can be styled:

```js
const pickerElem = document.createElement('input');
pickerElem.setAttribute ('type', 'color');
pickerElem.setAttribute ('style',  "position: absolute; "
  + "top: 10px;" + "left: 10px;"
  + "width: 100px;" + "height: 100px;");
document.body.appendChild(pickerElem);
```

**This draws the color well as expected, but with a white border about five pixels wide. I want to delete the white border.**

I've tried adding properties like: `border: none;`, `border-style: hidden;`, `padding: 0;`, `margin: 0;` and `border-color: none;` to the style, but the browser ignores them.

If I use `border-color: black;` the browser adds a thin black border around the inner white border, but doesn't change the inner border color.

**How can I style the picker to completely delete the inner white border?**

Comment: Can you give us a minimal reproducible example of what problem you are having?

Comment: The given code is enough to reproduce the problem already; and even in "plain HTML" form without any JS involved, the issue is present, as f.e. with the basic example under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#try_it Not sure if there is anything that can be done about it though. I was not able to identify any property to "turn it off", and hiding it via a clip-path or something would rely on a magic number of "about five pixels", but if any browser applies a different one, that might again fail in unwanted ways.

Comment: If you eliminate the border and set `background: transparent`, the space will still be there, but less noticeable.

Comment: FYI: Looks like there _is_ a way to specify this directly after all, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471224/1427878

Answer (score 3):

Since the color picker render is mostly ruled by the browser and hard to custom style, you may choose to embed it inside a wrapper div and set its opacity as zero and yet have a way to pick the color chosen to style such wrapper.

Here I used a wrapper div styled with the css rule `.colorpicker` and its background color controlled by a function called when the `oninput` event triggers on the embedded color picker:

```js
function changeWrapperColor(embeddedColorPicker) {
  embeddedColorPicker.parentElement
    .style.backgroundColor = embeddedColorPicker.value;  
}
```

```css
.colorpicker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border: dashed 4px gray;
}

.colorpicker input[type="color"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorpicker">
  <input type="color" oninput="changeWrapperColor(this)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! @Mr._Polywhirl took your idea further, [his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77789391/15167500) is more complex.

Answer (score 3):

As Diego suggested, you could wrap your input in a wrapper and update the background color on `change`.

This solution below provides a reusable function (plugin) that can be used to handle multiple inputs. It is even capable of syncing inputs with predefined `value` attributes.

```js
CustomColorPicker(); // Invoke

function CustomColorPicker(className = '.color-picker') {
  function syncWithInput(colorPicker) {
    if (!colorPicker) return;
    const input = colorPicker.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
    if (!input) return;
    colorPicker.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
    colorPicker.title = input.value; // Update tooltip
  }

  function handleColorChange({ target }) {
    syncWithInput(target.closest(className));
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(syncWithInput);
  document.addEventListener('change', handleColorChange);
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 1rem; background: #222; }

.color-picker {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: black;
  border: dashed thin white;
  width: 3rem; /* You can change this */
}

.color-picker > input[type="color"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Red -->
<div class="color-picker">
  <input type="color" value="#FF0000" />
</div>
<!-- Green -->
<div class="color-picker">
  <input type="color" value="#00FF00" />
</div>
<!-- Blue -->
<div class="color-picker">
  <input type="color" value="#0000FF" />
</div>
```

If you want a way to cleanup the plugin, you can have it return a destructor function to remove event listeners.

```js
const cleanupFn = CustomColorPicker(); // Invoke

function destroy() {
  cleanupFn(); // Call the plugin destructor
  console.log('Tearing-down the plugin');
}

function CustomColorPicker(className = '.color-picker') {
  function syncWithInput(colorPicker) {
    if (!colorPicker) return;
    const input = colorPicker.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
    if (!input) return;
    colorPicker.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
    colorPicker.title = input.value; // Update tooltip
  }

  function handleColorChange({ target }) {
    syncWithInput(target.closest(className));
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(syncWithInput);
  document.addEventListener('change', handleColorChange);
  
  // Destructor function
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('change', handleColorChange);
  };
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 1rem; background: #222; }

.color-picker {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: black;
  border: dashed thin white;
  width: 3rem; /* You can change this */
}

.color-picker > input[type="color"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 1rem;">
  <!-- Red -->
  <div class="color-picker">
    <input type="color" value="#FF0000" />
  </div>
  <!-- Green -->
  <div class="color-picker">
    <input type="color" value="#00FF00" />
  </div>
  <!-- Blue -->
  <div class="color-picker">
    <input type="color" value="#0000FF" />
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="destroy()">Destroy</button>
```

Comment: I love short, clever, reusable solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Addendum:
I should have been clearer about my motivation to remove the inner white border: if the border can be removed, the picker element can be made invisible by styling the color well down to zero dimensions. Then, using a simulated mouse event, I can cause a click on any element (text, SVG shape, whatever) to directly bring up the browser's color dialog. This gives access to the full range of the browser's color selection tools, such as the color wheel, HSB sliders, stored colors, eyedrop picker, etc., to set the color of the element.

Unfortunately, I found that styling the color well to width=0 and height=0 removed the color well but left a small white square that is the remains of the white border (using the Safari 14 browser). The above answers to my original question indicate that it may be difficult to reliably (cross-browser) remove that white square.

But don't despair. Since I'm simulating a mouse event to bring up the picker, the color well and its border need not be visible. I can style it off screen before the browser paints it and it appears to the user that the click in the onscreen element directly brought up the picker interface. It's a bit of a hack but the user's experience is exactly what i was looking for.

Note 1: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059006/simulate-a-real-human-mouse-click-in-pure-javascript) for a discussion on how to simulate a mouse click. Thanks @Iván!

Note 2: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167281/webkit-css-to-control-the-box-around-the-color-in-an-inputtype-color/11471224) for a detailed discussion and solutions for my original question. Thanks @CBroe for your comment pointing this out.

Note 3: I wasted days searching for solutions and trying different approaches. The StackOverflow page referenced above in Note 2 would have quickly solved my problem. Unfortunately the page title specified "the box around the color" which never came up in searches for "color picker border" and similar terms. StackOverflow's usual good editing somehow didn't happen here.