# simulate a click on an element in chrome extension from content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i have tried 2 things :-
`.click()` method in javascript and

```
function simulateClick(onElement) {
  let mouseClick = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  mouseClick.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  let cb = onElement;
  let canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(mouseClick);
}
```

this `simulateclick()` function. 
i want to simulate a click on this website
https://contacts.google.com/
on the **Create a contact** button which comes after clicking on **Create contact** button, above the **Create multiple contacts**. please go to the link and look up the issue. so far whatever i have tried, none work. i would realy appreciate an explanation behind this. thank you!

Comment: `onElement.click()` should work.

Comment: I have a content script that clicks on a link, and that's all I do.

Comment: Your going to have difficulties as the "Create Contact" button only appears at certain viewport widths. At smaller ones, a different button is added at the bottom of the screen. If you can overcome this issue, as the buttons are not named for the end user, you just need to invoke the `click()` method. As a suggestion, you might be better off using the Google Contacts API instead of hacking something through JS.

Comment: @Barmar that does not work, i have already tried that.

Comment: @Itanex i didn't get you.. also, i am able to select that element by this query document.querySelectorAll(".z80M1")[4] but cannot click on it using the .click() method.

Comment: You can try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43331339/3930351)

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but `initMouseEvent` is deprecated. You should initialize the event as shown in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: I was going to suggest that you make sure the event bubbles, but that's what the second argument to `initMouseEvent` specifies.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the web page isn't actually using the click event for this, maybe `mousedown`.

Comment: These controls both use a `<button>` element to capture the event. So the `element.click()` event will work just fine. @SanketChauhan, I completely understand what your doing here. You do not need to create an `event` or use the `dispatchEvent` method. Capture the button and execute its native `click()` method. As the reason your not able to use the `click()` that query returns a `<span>` not the `<button>` try this `document.querySelector(".gl6QPb")`

Comment: @SanketChauhan turns out the button doesn't trigger this functionality. There is a framework that I am not familiar with running on the page. I was under the impression that it was Angular, but after investigating a bit, I do not recognize the HTML attributes.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help, will try and get back.

Comment: @Itanex as mentioned in the question i am able to simulate a click on the first **Create contact** and not on the second. the query you specified is for the first one. i appreciate your effort, thank you. but you're unable to understand my problem. :(

Comment: @IvánNokonoko worked like a charm, thank you so much! :D

Comment: @SanketChauhan  If it worked, remember to upvote it :)